# Is IronPython + XNA a serious contender for game development?

Tags: python, xna, ironpython

I do enjoy the other multimedia libraries for Python, however I am curious if IronPython and XNA could be a contender for game development. Is there any reason why you don't hear of this too often?

Also, this was meant to be more or less a topic regarding Python and IronPython. I know there are other languages that may be better suited but I am only curious about Python, Jython, Cython, IronPython etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using IronPython + XNA, instead of C# + XNA, you lose XNA's cross-platform capabilities.

You cannot run IronPython on the Xbox 360 or Windows Phone 7 ([see this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/xnaframework/thread/3c34b4b0-bba3-4c92-8de0-13ffc1d311d9)). I also suspect that you won't be able to use other cross-platform XNA implementations (eg: my own [ExEn](http://andrewrussell.net/exen/)).

Also there is, of course, a performance disadvantage to using IronPython instead of C#. I can't say what the performance differences between IronPython and other python implementations might be - but those other implementations can't really be used with XNA anyway.

Other than that, I can't really think of any functional differences. If your target is Windows, then XNA + IronPython should be just fine for game development.

Although if you are choosing XNA as your platform, and doing a "serious" project, then C# is probably the better *primary* language choice, as it is better supported.